# How does Python access OS API functions such as socket()?

Tags: python, sockets

UPDATED Questions:

1. Where does the socket object actually get created? I found this at line 4188 in [socketmodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/socketmodule.c), but it looks like it's called sock_new not socket?

   ```
   static PyObject *sock_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
   ```
2. Is there some convention for figuring out where a module like socketmodule.c is imported? In other words, when I see a "from _socket import *" who do I know what that's importing (without searching the whole repository)?

---

ORIGINAL:

```
sock_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
```

I'm trying to understand how this code works specifically how/where Python actually makes the OS function call to socket():

```
class _socketobject(object):

    __doc__ = _realsocket.__doc__

    __slots__ = ["_sock", "__weakref__"] + list(_delegate_methods)

    def __init__(self, family=AF_INET, type=SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, _sock=None):
        if _sock is None:
            _sock = _realsocket(family, type, proto)
        self._sock = _sock
        for method in _delegate_methods:
            setattr(self, method, getattr(_sock, method))
```

When I look up BSD sockets on Wikipedia I see this example which makes sense because the socket function is defined under types.h. In the above I see a call to realsocket which look like an OS function call, but I don't realsocket defined anywhere (I don't see anything about sockets at all in the Python27/include headers).

```
  /* Server code in C */

  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <sys/socket.h>
  #include <netinet/in.h>
  #include <arpa/inet.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <unistd.h>

  int main(void)
  {
    struct sockaddr_in stSockAddr;
    int SocketFD = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
```

Comment: For me, there's a socket.py in the Python27/lib folder.  There are some comments within the file that describe available platform-specific function calls.

Comment: _realsocket = socket at https://github.com/certik/python-2.7/blob/master/Lib/socket.py#L100

Comment: In `Python2.7.10` tarball, `Modules/socketmodule.c` line 3192 (in `sock_initobj` func) `fd = socket(family, type, proto);`. `sock_new` just creates the `Python` wrapper object. As for your second question `socket.py` is simply a wrapper over `_socket.so` and it exposes everything that the dynamic module does (+ a few things). You can import `_socket` directly and see its members.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has everything to do with the 1<sup>st</sup> and the 2<sup>nd</sup> lines from *socket.py*:

```py
import _socket
from _socket import *
```

If you start *Python* and run the following code:

```py
import socket
print dir(socket)
print dir(socket._socket)
```

you'll notice that *socket* only exports a few extra things compared to `socket._socket`.

Now, what is `socket._socket`? It is a *Python* dynamic module (meaning that it can be used just like any other python module), but it's written in *C* (so after compilation it has an *OS* specific native form: *.so* under *Nix* and *.dll* (*.pyd*) under *Win*). Its location is in the python lib folder (where *socket.py* is also located): *lib-dynload/_socket*.so*.

You can see where modules are located by printing them (in the same console where you ran the above code you could type):

```py
print socket
print socket._socket
```

If you're more interested, its source code is located in the *Python* source tarball in *${PYTHON_SRC_DIR}/Modules/socketmodule.c* (it also has a header file). In those files, the wrapper functions (that are visible from *Python*) are defined and they call the native functions (e.g. ***socket*** from */usr/include/sys/socket.h*).

Comment: This is such a freaking helpful answer!  Thanks!  Helped me understand socketmodule.c also!

Comment: Glad to be helpful!